# Widget Firing Continuously in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter development. i'm calling widget in build, first time(landing screen) it's working fine. i'm going to another screen and come back to the landing screen the widget firing continuously and showing Blank screen.

```dart
body: Container(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                  child: Text('Total Orders - ' + _orders['orders'].toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          ),
                    ),
                ),
                _buildOrdersChart(context, model, _orders),
              ],
          ),
      ),
```

```
Widget _buildOrdersChart(BuildContext context, MainModel model, _orders) {
    var data = [
      Sales('DineIn', _orders['DineIn'].toInt(), Colors.teal[800]),
      Sales('Delivery', _orders['Delivery'].toInt(), Colors.pink[800]),
      Sales('TakeAway', _orders['Takeaway'].toInt(), Colors.lime[900]),
    ];

    var series = [
      charts.Series(
          domainFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.day,
          measureFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.sold,
          colorFn: (Sales sales, _) => sales.color,
          id: 'Sales',
          data: data,
          labelAccessorFn: (Sales sales, _) => '${sales.sold.toString()}')
    ];

    var chart = charts.PieChart(
      series,
      animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      defaultRenderer:
          charts.ArcRendererConfig(arcWidth: 100, arcRendererDecorators: [
        charts.ArcLabelDecorator(labelPosition: charts.ArcLabelPosition.inside)
      ]),
    );}
```

Comment: it can be issue with _buildOrdersChart(context, model, _orders) while passing the data and try to print the value of variable _orders in the console to see proper output is getting or not

Comment: @YashJain when i print _orders getting correct data.

Comment: could you add the code when you call from landing screen to another screen ?

Comment: @JagadeeshSimhadri ok

Comment: can you please share _buildOrdersChart function code to validate, it will provide better visibility while debug.

Comment: @Anandsaga can u check my edited question

Comment: @diegoveloper can u check my edited question

Comment: Add the code when you push the new screen from the landing